# Como hacer un operador ternario dentro de operador ternario?

Tags: react-native, operador-ternario

Tengo un boton en react native, que se encuentra apagado (Styles.Button), el cual debe activarse (Styles.buttonEnabled) una vez que isValid detecte información en los inputs, después el usuario toma la foto de su credencial, entonces idValidated detecta correctamente la foto, el mismo boton debe volverse verde (Styles.ButtonValidated). He intentado usar en style un operador ternario dentro de otro operador ternario, pero no parece funcionar, espero alguien pueda darme una idea, gracias

```
                        <Button
                            mode="outlined"
                            style={
                                isValid
                                    ? idValidated
                                        ? Styles.ButtonValidated
                                        : Styles.buttonEnabled
                                    : Styles.Button
                            }
                            color={colors.red}
                            labelStyle={Styles.labelTextButton}
                            uppercase={false}
                            onPress={attemps < 3 ? handleScanID : handleErrorAttemps}
                            loading={loading}
                            disabled={idValidated || !isValid}
                            icon={idValidated ? 'check' : null}
                        >
                            {idValidated ? 'Identidad validada' : 'Validar identidad'}
                        </Button>
```

Estos son mis Styles de cada boton:

```
Button: {
    backgroundColor: colors.light_blue,
    borderColor: colors.light_blue,
},
buttonEnabled: {
    backgroundColor: colors.blue,
    borderColor: colors.blue,
},
ButtonValidated: {
    backgroundColor: colors.light_green,
    borderColor: colors.light_green,
}
```

})

Comment: Así sin ver el resto del código, sin saver lo que es isValid, idValidated, Styles.... lo único que veo es que te sobran las llaves

Comment: Pues en teoría debería estar bien. por favor, edita la pregunta y pon el valor de Styles, porque puede que le pases un valor incorrecto y por eso no aparece. los valores incorrectos no aparecen en el inspeccionador de código

Comment: gracias, ya los agregué

Comment: Perdona que insista, pero yo creo que el probelma están en la variable Styles, así que deberías poner también el valor de colors ya que creo que se le está pasando un valor incorrecto

Comment: te refieres a colors en los estilos de cada boton?  o a la propiedad que está dentro de la etiqueta Button?

Comment: a la variable colors que usas en Styles

Comment: colors es otro archivo 'colors.ts' donde tengo guardados cada color que llamo en la hoja de estilos, y por ejemplo con ese ternario que puse arriba, el boton inicial si se ve color light blue, y al final del proceso se ve light green, a mi parecer es el ternario el que no me funciona, ya que nunca cae en el caso donde activa el buttonEnabled que es color blue

Comment: Pues no se, prueba a hacer el ternario fuera y asignarlo a una variable cualquiera, luego asigna esa variable a la propiedad style. Esto no varía nada, pero podrás imprimir por consola el valor que tenga esa propiedad y ver si pasa algo raro

Comment: por ejemplo estuve alternando los botones en el ternario, y si pude ver todos los botones, pero solo 2 al mismo tiempo, nunca los 3 que requiere el proceso completo

Comment: Esto ultimo ya me he perdido, no se si es porque falta código o lo que sea. pero ese botón solo muestr 1 botón, lo que varía son los estilos

Comment: una disculpa, si me refería a los estilos, el boton cambiaba dos veces de estilos, y lo que quiero hacer ahora es incluir un tercer estilo, en el operador ternario

Comment: Yo he probado el ternario y funciona perfectamente, segun los valores de las variables que lo controlan me muestran el botón con el color que tiene que ser, prueba a hacer lo que te puse hace 2 comentarios, hacer el ternario en una variable y asignarsela a la propiedad style del Button y a imprimirla por consola

Comment: El operador ternario es azúcar sintáctico. Si combinas varios solo lograrás tener un código más difícil de leer. Pero si insistes, usa paréntesis para facilitar la lectura.

Comment: al parecer si era el ternario, este me funcionó al final:         style={
         idValidated
          ? Styles.ButtonValidated
          : isValid
          ? Styles.buttonEnabled
          : Styles.Button
        }